# Websockets on a VPS with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, websocket

I deployed a Java webapp that uses websockets via the Spring framework on a Ubuntu VPS on a Tomcat7.

Everything is working besides websockets - during the initial handshake, I get :

```
 WebSocket connection to
 'ws://x.x.x.x:8080/stomp/738/d4se5uwf/websocket' failed: Error
 during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

As you can see, I temporarily opened the 8080 port to eliminate the fact that my Tomcat7 is fronted by an Apache2 and I'm directly querying my home page with http://x.x.x.x:8080, where a script initiates the websocket connection.

However Tomcat still refuses to act as a websocket server for the connection upgrade.

Locally everything works fine with

```
ws://localhost:8080/stomp/.....
```

What could cause this difference ?

Some additional info :

- when manually typed in the browser address bar, ws://localhost:8080/stomp/ and ws://x.x.x.x:8080/stomp both give 404
- when manually typed in the browser address bar, http://localhost:8080/stomp/ and http://x.x.x.x:8080/stomp both print a "welcome to SockJS !" page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which was simply to copy `tomcat7-websocket.jar` and `websocket-api.jar` to the Tomcat's `/lib` directory.

The jar's were apparently not included in the release that I got